# Linux 4.4 kernel changes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In last month Sles12 sp2 is released. In this release 4.4 linux kernel is being used whereas in sles12sp1 the kernel version was 3.12. 
It is obvious that so many features and code changes are added in the sles12 sp2 kernel (i .e 4.4 kernel) .

I had written a driver for 3.12 kernel; now I want to make my driver workable for 4.4 kernel. The one way is to compile driver code for 4.4 kernel and fix the compilation error. But I want to figure out what are the exact changes made between 3.12 and 4.4 kernel, to utilize new features of 4.4 kernel in my driver efficiently.

Where can I find that what are changes made between 3.12 and 4.4 kernel and how make my driver workable for 4.4 kernel easily and efficiently?

Comment: Fix the errors one by one. This is easiest way to achieve the result. Btw, are you sure there is no ustream available driver for your case?

Answer (score 1):

I would use git to show the changes. You can clone the upstream git tree from https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git

Then you can use commands like:

```
git log (-p) v3.12..v4.4 -- (paths that you are interested in)
tig v3.12..v4.4
git diff v3.12..v4.4 -- (paths that you are interested in)
```

You can read about changes from [https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions?action=show&redirect=Linux26Changes](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.13)